# Cut bottom left corner from box with straight line

Tags: html, css

I would like to cut bottom down corner of the box. I found in other answers that it can be done with `linear-gradient`. However, I noticed that when I am using `linear-gradient` the corner is not cut with straight line, but with somehow saw line.

How can I cut the cornet with straight line? Did I configured `linear-gradient` in the wrong way?

```css
.box {
  background-color: #231f20;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(35deg, transparent 15px, #231f20 10px);
}
```

```html
  <div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: how exactly would you like to cut? It does look like you have done it right. [link](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)

Comment: use clip-path (read all the answers in the duplicate)

Comment: I found that an easy way to achieve this is to use a gradient generator instead of writing my own gradient. Only to save time but it does save a lot of time. So I usually set up any type of gradient that I can imagine but on one side for approx the last 3% or 5% it is transparent. If you make it a 45 degree slant that transparent bit will be your corner. Just one problem. Different size boxes mean a different level of 3%, 5% etc. It's possible that boxes do not appear uniform with different sized corners.

Comment: @MilanSachani I want to cut it with straight line. If you check my example closely, you will see it is not straight line.

@TemaniAfif I thought that `clip-path` is not supported by all browsers. Can you give me a code sample here in comment, since the question is closed?

Comment: @CuteyfromCuteCode Thank you! That was it. When I changed it to 45deg the edge is cut with straight line.

Comment: Usually at this point I would convert the comment to an answer but you seem to have been moderated a little :) :) :)

Comment: Yup. They closed my question right away, even it's not the same as duplicate specified. I didn't asked general question, but explicit problem with code sample. You definitely deserve upvote and accepter answer. :D